# proving Riemann-Lebesgue lemma

Tags: fourier-analysis

I have looked at proofs of the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma on the internet; all of these proofs use the technique of Riemann integration and making step functions.

E.g.(https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Riemann-Lebesgue_Lemma)

But if we know Parseval's identity (or Plancherel's identity for Fourier transform)
then, can I use
$$
\sum_{-\infty}^\infty |a_n|^2 = \|f\|^2 = M<\infty
$$

[image]

then the tails of the sum is very small, $a_n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$?

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot, Parseval's Identity works in Hilbert spaces, e.g. $L^2$ but not in a general Banach space e.g. $L^1$.

Comment: but the only condition for Parseval's Identity is the Integrability??

Comment: @mnmn1993 If you have $\infty=\infty$ in Parseval's identity, this does not help you prove that the terms go to zero.

Answer (score 0):

This shows RL Lemma for $ L^2 $ then we can extend it to $ L^1 $ by density.

Answer (score 0):

There's a really nice proof that "avoids step functions".

With a $u-$substitution you can conclude that $$ \hat{f}(\xi) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)e^{ix\xi} dx 
\\ 
  = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x + \frac{\pi}{\xi})e^{ix\xi}e^{i \pi}  dx \\   
  = - \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x + \frac{\pi}{\xi})e^{ix\xi} \ dx $$

By averaging these two representations of Fourier transform, we obtain  $$\hat{f}(\xi) = \frac{1}{2} \int_{\mathbb{R}} (f(x) - f(x + \pi/\xi) ) e^{ix\xi}  \ dx $$

Since $|e^{ix}| = 1$, we can then conclude that

$$\hat{f}(\xi) \leq \frac{1}{2} \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(x) - f(x+\pi/\xi)| dx $$

Letting $\xi \to 0$, finishes the proof assuming we can interchange limits and the integral. We can, but the proof of why (at least the ones I know) still require that step function type argument which is why I put "avoid step functions" in quotes.